# Deriving range of a equation from its inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I was solving a question that involved finding the range of a function:

[image]

If I invert the equation I get:
$$\frac x{1+x^2}=\left(\frac{1+x^2}x\right)^{-1}$$
I know the range of the RHS above is $(-\infty,-2)\cup(+2,+\infty)$. If I invert the above range that I got it will be $(-1/2,1/2)$, which is the correct answer for the given question.

Does this always work? Does finding the range of the inverted equation and inverting the range give me the answer I want always? I am really curious to know, I know the method to equating the equation to y and finding the range, but wanted to know if this works too.

Comment: ∧ : this is the exponent symbol...it's not working on my keyboard so I had to copy and paste this sketchy looking symbol from the net.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it always works whenever the transformation is defined, as you will see by setting $y=f(x),$ so that taking reciprocals gives $$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{f(x)}.$$ Then if you know that $a\le 1/y \le b,$ say, then provided requisite conditions are satisfied we have that $1/a\ge y\ge 1/b,$ which gives you a range of values of $y=f(x),$ the original you sought. In practice this may become very complicated. By the way your function here has a nice property (as does its reciprocal), namely that $f(1/x)=f(x)$ whenever these are defined, namely for $x\ne 0.$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work always, it has worked here just by chance. So, never try to fall in such short tricks, the best way to approach for finding the range of a problem is to find $dy/dx$, where $y$ is the function and equate to $0$ and then applying the first and second-order derivatives

Comment: There are still other prevalent ways,like plotting the curve, but still it needs the knowledge of differentiation